# Trouble with subscriptable object - TypeError:

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get the following block of code to work:

```
for r in roles:
        role = Role.query.filter_by(name=r).first()
        if role is None:
            role = Role(name=r)
        role.permissions = roles[r][0]
        role.default = roles[r][1] 
        db.session.add(role)
    db.session.commit()
```

However I'm getting the following:

```
role.permissions = roles[r][0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to do str(roles[r][0] but that didn't work either... any ideas?

Edit: Here is the Dictionary Code:

```
def insert_roles():
    roles = {

    'User': (Permission.FOLLOW |
        Permission.COMMENT),

    'Moderator': (Permission.FOLLOW |
        Permission.COMMENT |
        Permission.MODERATE_COMMENTS, True),

    'Administrator': (0xff, False)
    }
```

Comment: is `roles` a dictionary here?

Comment: roles is a dictionary yup

Comment: So what are your dictionary values? According to your error message, they're integers.

Comment: i added the dictionary values to my original comment to help clarify

Comment: `roles['User']` is an `int`, seemingly. Did you forget the second boolean element in the tuple for it?

Answer (score 0):

(Converting my comment to an answer)

In your code, `roles['User']` is an `int`, seemingly. Did you forget the second boolean element in the tuple for it?

`(Permission.FOLLOW | Permission.COMMENT)`  is an  `int` -- not even a tuple with one element. You might want to change that to:

```
(Permission.FOLLOW | Permission.COMMENT, True) # Or False, however your case maybe.
```